# Pass mulitple parameters in REST API

Tags: rest-api, salesforce-id

I am fairly new to Rest API concept and learning from forums.

I have connected my two dev-orgs using Rest. So, when i create an Account record in source org, it gets created in destination org too. This works fine when I just pass "Name".

But I am also trying to pass source org's Account ID to Destination org's Description field. This isn't working though account are created (only description is not passing). Below is my code,

```
 if(accessToken!=null){
        String endPoint='https://vigneshdev-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/Account'; //Change "ap4" in url to your Target Org Instance 


        JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeStringField('Name', AccName);
        gen.writeStringField('Description', ID);

        gen.writeEndObject();

        Http h2= new Http();
        HttpRequest req2= new HttpRequest();
        req2.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + accessToken);
        req2.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        req2.setHeader('accept','application/json');
        req2.setBody(gen.getAsString());
        req2.setMethod('POST');
        system.debug('>>>req2' + req2.getBody());
        req2.setEndpoint(endPoint);
        HttpResponse res2=h2.send(req2);
        deserializeResponse deresp2=(deserializeResponse)System.JSON.deserialize(res2.getBody(),deserializeResponse.class);
```

can i have some suggestions regarding this?

Comment: Does the profile which you are using to create the Account record in the target org has access to the `Description` field?

Comment: Also what does your response look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran the following cut down version of your code as anonymous Apex:

```
Account acc = [Select Id, Name from Account limit 1];
JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
gen.writeStartObject();
gen.writeStringField('Name', acc.Name);
gen.writeStringField('Description', acc.Id);
gen.writeEndObject();

System.debug(gen.getAsString());

String strURL = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm();
string endpoint = strURL + '/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/Account';
System.debug(endpoint);

Http h2= new Http();
HttpRequest req2 = new HttpRequest();
req2.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
req2.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
req2.setHeader('accept','application/json');
req2.setBody(gen.getAsString());
req2.setMethod('POST');
req2.setEndpoint(endPoint);

HttpResponse res2=h2.send(req2);
System.debug(res2.getBody());
```

The JSON payload for the POST request debugged out as:

```
{
  "Name" : "Test Account 1",
  "Description" : "00140000000001KAAU"
}
```

The CALLOUT_RESPONSE in the debug log was:

> System.HttpResponse[Status=Created, StatusCode=201]

And the response body:

```
{"id":"0011W00001zex6SQAQ","success":true,"errors":[]}
```

I queried the resulting Account by Id and it had the Description field set to the expected value.

---

So, it works in the simplest case.

That your Description field isn't being populated in the created record suggests a few possible things are occurring:

1. The `ID` is null or empty before the JSON payload is even created.
2. The user who the API callout session belongs to doesn't have write access to the Description field in the target org.
3. There is some automation in the target org that is changing the value in the Description field.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I had a trigger in destination org which changed the description to null.. Missed it :)